# Dynamic height label in container view in scroll view

Tags: ios, autolayout, interface-builder

I have a screen with static content at the top and a container view on the bottom, both of which are in a scroll view. The container view has multiple child views it switches between, most of which are table views, but one of them contains just a dynamic height label. I have set up the view hierarchy and constraints like this:

[image]

For the child views with tables, I am able to set the scroll view content size to match the total height of the content by adding the top view's height and the table view's content size height. I also set the container view's height to match the table view's content height, and everything works wonderfully. Here's the code I use for that:

```
bottomContainerHeightConstraint.constant = tableVC.tableView.contentSize.height
scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: scrollView.contentSize.width, height: topContainer.frame.size.height + tableVC.tableView.contentSize.height)
```

Now I am trying to do something similar with my last child VC that has just a label with all four sides bound to it's parent view, but I cannot figure out how to get the child view to resize based on the content height, or how to get the content height. I've tried using `systemLayoutSizeFittingSize`, but it just gives me the initial size of the container view and causes the label to truncate. How do I get the correct height for the child view so that the label won't truncate? Or is there a better way to set up my views in IB so that autolayout will do this automatically?